# Submitting a html form with javascript/ajax/php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, onclick, progress-bar

Evening, I seem to have hit an issuee with submitting this html form via a javascript `onclick()` function. This is my first time trying this, and i am new to js/ajax, however from my understanding of both i am doing this correctly... In the end this is my goal: user enters info - javascript/ajax constructs GET request and sends it - my php form runs each input field as its own query, every time the query is ran, it then echos the percentage of progress (after each query it runs) - which then (via the ajax) returns that percentage to my HTML5 progress bar (kudos to the new `<prgress>` tag.) and in turns creates a progress bar. however 
 1. I think i may be going about this wrong
 2. the way im doing this should work
 3. Im at the end of my rope...

here is my js:

```
function reply(){
 var total = document.getElementById("setName").name;
  var firstArray = new Array();
   for(i = 1; i <= total; i++){
    firstArray[] = "i = document.getElementById(i)";
   }
  //implode firstArray for uset in $_GET
  //aparently its called join...
  var GET = firstArray.join('&');

    //need to set up xml to run php for query
     if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
       xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
     else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
       xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }

     xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
       if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
         document.getElementById("progressBar").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
       }
     };
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajaxQuery.php?"+GET,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Again, I am new to js/ajax, but not PHP, running the querys is not a problem and that part is working flawless, but this wont even run the onclick.... any and all help is apreciated guys.

as a side note, my input fields use numbers as name attribute, to better interact with the js, but here is the onclick call

```
<button type = "button" onClick = "reply()">Submit</button>
```

I understand this could be A LOT better, feel free to tear it apart, the best way to learn is to be critisized on ones mistakes :)

Comment: Why dont you try a framework like jquery? This will keep you out of the trouble messing around with activeX and XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: @John im hardly familiar with js /ajax let alone jquery :P I saw this way working in my head, and it is my plan to see it through :P

Comment: jQuery makes it way easier to understand. Try this: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery

Comment: @John Ill look over it, but that doesnt exactly fix this^ :P

Comment: can you try `<input type = "button" onclick = "reply()" value="Submit"/>` (I dont know if button (HTML5) still accepts onclick (old method)). If it doesnt ill rewrite your code with jQuery ;-)

Comment: Cost-benefit/efficiency speaking, you should learn jQuery instead of raw JavaScript. 15 lines in your code can be replaced with a single jQuery line. JavaScript's inconsistent syntax on different browsers will confuse you. I wouldn't say the same for PHP which is good if you learn it raw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to rewrite some of your code with jQuery. It should work, but I did not test it:

```
<!--Import jQuery --> <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {
        $("#submitButton").click(function(){
            reply();
        })
    });

    function reply(){
        var total = document.getElementById("setName").name;
        var firstArray = new Array();
        for(i = 1; i <= total; i++){
            firstArray[] = "i = document.getElementById(i)";
        }
        //implode firstArray for uset in $_GET
        //aparently its called join...
        var GET = firstArray.join('&');     

        var jqxhr = $.ajax( {
            type: "GET",
            url: "ajaxQuery.php?"+GET
        } )
        .done(function(data) { 
            $("#progressBar").html( data );    
        });



    }
</script>

<button type = "button" id="submitButton">Submit</button>
```

Comment: for some reason that isntworking, i have narrowed it down to the onclick  not working im going to go over that tutorial you recomended and see if i can figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

To construct the query string, you should do something like this:

```
var firstArray = new Array(), qs;

for(i = 1; i <= total; i++){
    firstArray.push('i[]=' + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById(i).value);
}

// i[]=123&i[]=456&...
qs = firstArray.join('&');

// ...

xmlhttp.open("GET", "ajaxQuery.php?" + qs, true);
```

Btw, you shouldn't use elements with `id` attribute that starts with a number!